# How to delete cache after updating/deleting/adding new content using hooks?

Tags: 7, hooks, caching

We have a custom services module and a site in Drupal 7, and I got the task to delete the cache after the editor adds new content or update the existing ones.

I've read about a module called [Cache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/cache_actions), but, as i said, i need to create the function on my custom module.

Also, I've started reading about Drupal hooks, but still don't have a clue of how to implement this task. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: This could be implemented in a few ways. How often does your editor update/delete/add new content?

Comment: Very often, because we use drupal as the manager of the data to make web services for mobile apps. I couldn't tell you exactly how frequently we add or modify data, but the main request is to clear the cache every time a change happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you've already got a custom module, but just in case you haven't see the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

The hooks you're looking for are [`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [`hook_node_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7), and the function to clear the cache will either be [`cache_clear_all()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) or [`drupal_flush_all_caches`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/7). The former will let you clear specific [cache bins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7) (and even specific cache items), and the latter will clear absolutely everything.

For example:

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

or to clear only the static page cache after a node has been updated:

```
function MYMODULE_node_update($node) {
  $nodeurl = url('node/'. $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
  cache_clear_all($nodeurl, 'cache_page');
}
```

Comment: Ok, i understand it. Just one more question, do i have to add the code in my .module file or in the node module file of drupal?

Comment: It goes in your own module file, hacking core files is a big no-no in Drupal :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily clear specific node cache after updating them. Ex. :

```
function MYMODULE_node_update($node) {
  $nodeurl = url('node/'. $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
  cache_clear_all($nodeurl, 'cache_page');
}
```

Please note that you must need to specify `array('absolute' => TRUE)`.