# Does hook_node_submit() fire on feed import?

Tags: 7, feeds, nodes

If I implement `hook_node_submit()`, will it be invoked when I import nodes from a feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe hook_node_submit() only gets fired when submitting a node form. So the answer to your question is no.

I think you might be better off using hook_node_presave(). This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the database.

Comment: I need something that clears the cache when a content person goes in and changes something. Doing this when EVERY node saves would cause a site crash due to the amount of data pulled in through a feed.

Comment: @Heather Is there a way you can run cache_clear_all() after data is pulled through the feed?

Comment: I don't want it to. It runs on cron anyway. I just need clear_cache_all() to run when a user goes in and edits or adds content, not when all nodes are created. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Heather perhaps hook_node_update() and hook_node_insert() will help you. Check this answer out: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48600/how-to-delete-cache-after-updating-deleting-adding-new-content-using-hooks#answer-48604